# Org mode 9.2.6 - Org agenda - match tags/prop/todo query hangs

Tags: org-mode

After typing a keyword the command just hangs, regardless of the query.

The trace is as follows:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (quit)
  org-add-prop-inherited("qpct")
  #[257 "\300!\262\301!\207" [copy-sequence org-add-prop-inherited] 3 "\n\n(fn X)"]("qpct")
  mapcar(#[257 "\300!\262\301!\207" [copy-sequence org-add-prop-inherited] 3 "\n\n(fn X)"] ("qpct"))
  org-scan-tags(agenda (lambda (todo tags-list level) (progn (setq org-cached-props nil) (or (and (member "bug" tags-list))))) nil)
  org-tags-view(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-tags-view nil)
  call-interactively(org-tags-view)
  org-agenda()
  org-agenda-append-agenda()
  funcall-interactively(org-agenda-append-agenda)
  call-interactively(org-agenda-append-agenda nil nil)
  command-execute(org-agenda-append-agenda)
```

Is anyone facing the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my issue by force recompiling of all the packages. I think things got messed up after a recent update of packages. Along with issues with org agenda, I was also seeing issues with org html export.

I ran the following function:
`(byte-recompile-directory package-user-dir nil 'force)`